# Why i get this Java error in VSCODE only?

Tags: java, swing, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

I get this error message:

> The method setLayout(LayoutManager) in the type JFrame is not
> applicable for the arguments (BorderLayout)

While running this Java code:

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;

public class Examen2 extends JFrame {

    public Examen2() {
        inicializarComponentes();
    }

    public void inicializarComponentes() {
        
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(600, 400);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    }

    class Panel extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Examen2().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

If I run this using the console or JGrasp it compiles just fine, only VSCode has a problem with it, but why?

Comment: Compiles OK with Java 17u6 from the command line.  My guess would be that it is a VSCode config issue.  Or ... maybe you have your own version of `BorderLayout` in your VSCode project?  Or this code that you are compiling is subtly different to what you are showing us?

Comment: Is it possible to modify like this?   `this.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());`

Comment: I don't have my own version of BorderLayout. Also VSCode offers me a quick fix which is to do a casting like this:

this.setLayout((LayoutManager)new BorderLayout());

And It works.